# Play Framework exception when using Java 7 multi-catch

Tags: playframework, java-7, multi-catch

I'm using Play 2.1.3 and for some strange reason it seems that I can't use the Java 7 [multi-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) construct. I can use diamonds or strings in switch, so Play is using Java 7 for sure.

This is the exception I get when loading the controller that uses multi-catch. Any idea?

(The `controllers.PurchasesController.submitData` method referred in the stack trace is the one that contains the multi-catch).

```
! Internal server error, for (GET) [/es/purchase] ->

java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 307 in method controllers.PurchasesController.submitData(Lplay/i18n/Lang;)Lplay/mvc/Result; at offset 293
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(MethodUtils.java:511) ~[commons-lang3.jar:3.1]
[error] application - Error while rendering default error page
scala.MatchError: java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 307 in method controllers.PurchasesController.submitData(Lplay/i18n/Lang;)Lplay/mvc/Result; at offset 293 (of class java.lang.VerifyError)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:103) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:161) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:79) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Server.scala:88) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
    at play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Server.scala:88) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
```